# Exchange Server automatically forwarding Emails

Tags: exchange-2007

We are running Small Business Server 2008, with Exchange 2007 built in.

We've just taken it over from another local IT guy.

They have emails for reception@abc123.com going straight to their admin@abc123.com account.

There is no Reception account setup in Mailbox, under recipient configuration and under the Admin account, there is no mention of the Reception account.

Any suggestions on how I can investigate what is causing it to automatically forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like that's a proxy address. You can find out what object has that proxy address by using ADUC and creating a query as such:

proxyaddresses=smtp:reception@abc123.com

Answer (score 1):

Open an Outlook client connected to the Exchange server, type reception@abc123.com in the "To:" field and press CTRL-K; this will resolve the SMTP address to the Active Directory user account (or contact) it's associated with. From there, you can investigate.